# How to give Permissions to User based on taxonomy selected while creating a content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users, nodes

I have a taxonomy called Projects and it has terms like `Project1, Project2` etc.
I have added a user called `ProjectUser1`, and assigned a new role called `ProjectRole` with it.
Now I want to give Permissions to `ProjectRole` so that when ProjectUser1 logins, he can only see the content that has `Project1` taxonomy and he can Publish, Unpublish, Edit or Delete only those content. He shouldn't be able to see the contents which doesn't have `Project1` taxonomy.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have a pretty in depth answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118878/edit-content-if-taxonomy-country-united-kingdom/118898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access)

```
Access control for user roles based on taxonomy categories (vocabulary, terms).

Automatically controls access to nodes (based on their taxonomy terms).
Three node access permission types: View, Update, Delete.
```

Comment: I tried this, but non-admin user can still edit the other content which doesn't have that particular taxonomy, or he couldn't edit any content. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using taxonomy and roles, you should use the [Organic Group Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/og).
- Turn a new content type, for instance ProjectGroup, into a private group
- Make content type Project a group content
- Assign Projects and Users into their ProjectGroups

In order to give non-admin users the permission to publish and unpublish content, you can use the [Publish module](https://www.drupal.org/project/publishcontent)

Comment: I can't create new content type or taxonomy, I have to use the existing ones. Can you explain this please in more detail?
Suppose I have content type called `Event`, Taxonomy vocabulary "Country" and term "United Kingdom". Now I want to give permission to non-admin user if a content has Country = United Kingdom, then he can edit, publish, delete that particular content, but in general he can see all the contents.

Comment: I'm afraid using the Organic Group Module without being able to create a new content type isn't possible, sorry.